# How to deal with new levels in variable while making prediction in future using already trained model?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, nested-data

I have a dataset where students are nested in schools and school is my categorical variable with levels. In future, new school levels can be added while making prediction using already trained data. My question is, if a new level is passed to a trained data that was not present during model training, the model will throw an error in prediction. How do I handle this problem while training your model.

Comment: Similar Qs:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298137/dealing-with-new-factor-levels-in-a-regression-in-r  (also look at the post in the sidebar under "linked"),

Comment: Robert Long makes an excellent point that mixed models are an elegant solution to this.
 Another approach is to one hot encode the schools (assuming there are not too many) and then new schools will simply have a 0 in all the indicators.

Answer (score 2):

With nested data like this, a mixed effects model with random intercepts for schools and possibly other random effects is a good way to handle the non-independence of observations within schools and the limited sample of schools in the dataset.

Random effects are often considered as samples from a wider population, so this would seem to suit your use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.